# Is there any command-line, generic HTTP proxy (like Squid)?

Tags: command-line, proxy, http, squid

I can easily use Netcat (or, Socat) to capture traffic between my browser and a specific host:port.

But for Linux, does there exist any command-line counterpart of a Squid-like HTTP proxy that I can use to capture traffic between my HTTP client (either browser or command-line program) and any arbitrary host:port?

Comment: Related: [Linux, simple http proxy](http://serverfault.com/q/335085/1809)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Perl and Python (and probably Ruby as well) have simple kits that you can use to quickly build simple HTTP proxies.

In Perl, use [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Proxy). Here's the 3-line example from the documentation. Add filters to filter, log or rewrite requests or responses; see the documentation for examples.

```
use HTTP::Proxy;
my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new( port => 3128 );
$proxy->start;
```

In Python, use [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html). Here's some sample code lightly adapted from [effbot](http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm). Adapt the `do_GET` method (or others) to filter, log or rewrite requests or responses.

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import urllib
class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)
httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', 3128), Proxy)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The Python one worked for me for HTTP requests but it doesn't seem to support HTTPS requests.

Comment: @RussellSilva Try http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/ or https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596

Answer (score 7):

This may not be the best solution, but if you use *any* proxy then it will have a specific `host:port` so the netcat solution with still work, albeit you'll have to pick apart the proxy meta-data to make sense of it.

The easiest way to do this might be to use any random anonymization proxy out there and just channel all the traffic through `netcat`. (I.e., set your browser proxy to `localhost:port` and then forward the data to the real proxy.)

If you want to have a local proxy then a SOCKS5 proxy with `ssh -D <port> localhost` is probably your easiest option. Obviously, you need to tell your browser to use a "socks" proxy rather than an "http" proxy.

So, something like this (assuming your local machine accepts incoming ssh connections):

```
ssh -fN -D 8000 localhost
nc -l 8080 | tee capturefile | nc localhost 8000
```

Naturally, that'll only work for one browser connection attempt, and then exit, and I have not attempted to forward the return data to the browser, so you'll need your full `netcat` solution.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any name suggestions for anonymization proxies for Linux? I would prefer ones that are not as heavyweight as Squid (in terms of size, memory, startup speed), are startable by a non-`root` user, etc.

Comment: Also, I didn't follow your SOCKS5 proxy example. Could you please explain what is going on with the 2 invocations above? I, e.g. know that `ssh -fN -D ...` starts a SOCKS5 proxy on `localhost` port `8000`, but what does `nc -l ...` do? And, to which port should I make my browser point to: `8000` or `8080`?

Comment: @harry for an anomyzation proxy have a look at privoxy

Comment: When I say "anonymization proxy" I don't mean something you set up yourself: I mean an existing proxy out there on the net. @UlrichDangel suggests privoxy and I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: The `nc` commands accept all traffic from port 8080 and forward it to 8000. I did not provide a full `netcat` solution because your post suggested you already knew how to do that part.

Answer (score 2):

https://mitmproxy.org/

An example:

```
mitmdump  --ssl-insecure --mode reverse:google.com
```