# forwarding web traffic through a vps running on Ubuntu in another country

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ssh-tunneling, forwarding

I've got a vps in another country. And I'd like to forward all my web traffic through it. I know there are commercial options available in the market but I'd like to do it by myself for the sake of  experimentation, learning and some fun.

My vps runs Ubuntu 12.04x64. And I'm connecting to the vps through either a macbook or windows laptop.

Can someone please help me through a step by step guide as to how this can be achieved? Else any guidance in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use ssh-tunneling? I mean you could presumable setup Squid on your VPS and just point your browsers directly at it... Or is there more to your question?

Comment: Yes I'd like to use ssh-tunneling specifically in order to learn and understand it. However while we are at it,  could you also point me how to use squid for it?

Comment: You can do this using just Perl/Python/Ruby as well via the command line: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38850/is-there-any-command-line-generic-http-proxy-like-squid/38859#38859. Also you can use SSH to do something similar as well.

Answer (score 3):

SSH SOCKS5 Tunnelling using PuTTY:

- Firstly connect to your server via SSH using PuTTY.
- Right-click on the top bar and hit 'change settings'.
- Goto Connection/SSH/tunnels.
  Source port: 4567, select 'Dynamic' and hit 'Add'
- Open up your choice of browser, and configure the 'Manual Proxy settings' to listen on port 4567 on localhost (127.0.0.1).

In Firefox you do this by going to:
Firefox/Options/Network > Settings, 
selecting: 'Manual Proxy Settings' and inputting '127.0.0.1' into the 'SOCKS' column, with 4567 as your port.
Also type 'about:config' into the URL bar in Firefox and change the value of network.proxy.socks_remote_dns to true - this will then force all DNS requests through your SOCKS proxy. As far as I am aware this only works in Firefox - both Chrome and IE won't route your DNS requests through a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 2):

First, set-up [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/squid.html) -

```
sudo apt-get install squid
```

Follow the directions at the above link to configure it. Allow only `localhost` to be secure.

Then, set-up [port-forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) - from local port 3128 to remote port 3128 (to use the squid defaults); then configure your web-browser to use port 3128 and localhost as your proxy. Requests will go over the ssh port forward (encrypted) to the VPS, where they will arrive at your squid proxy which will then fetch the page and  return it to it's locally forwarded socket which will then (encrypted) come back to your browser. There will probably be some performance impacts. Don't forget to enable compression with your forward (that's `ssh -C`)!

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna try now. But should I be using local, remote or dynamic port forwarding?

Comment: @user2252999 From the link, "Local port forwarding is the most common type." And that is the kind you want to use.

Comment: First up it works and thanks for the help. However I still can't access sites such as netflix or hulu or spotify as I'm still detected to be coming from outside of US. How can they be fooled into thinking that the request is coming from within the country?

Comment: Where is your VPS?

Comment: NYC and I'm in Europe.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/squid-proxy-is-not-hiding-client-ip-address/) and then [verify](http://www.whatismyip.com/).

Comment: Whatismyip shows that I'm in NYC and shows the ip address of the vps. However somehow google and others including netflix still are able to determine that I'm coming from outside the US... google.com takes me to its regional page and netflix still says that I'm outta the country. Do I need to flush the cache?

Comment: Cache flushing didn't help.

Comment: You might need to clear your cookies. If whatsmyip is showing NYC, then the proxy is working. Did you disable X-Forwarded-For and restart squid?

Comment: Yes I did disable X-Forwarded-For and restarted the server. And the cookies are cleared too. However here is the interesting bit - even with X-Forwarded-For set to on, whatismyip shows that I'm in NYC, only difference being that regarding proxy it says 'no proxy detected'. With x-forwarded-for on it identifies squid proxy. Proxy: 192.241.184.811.1 localhost (squid/3.1.19)

Comment: And Netflix still shows you out of region?

Comment: yes it shows me out of region

Comment: And you're going to www.netflix.com, and not just hitting refresh on the bad region page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step tutorial to make it a VPN server. VPN will send all your internet traffic through an encrypted tunnel to your VPS:

First, install the `pptpd` package. `pptpd` offers a PPTP-type VPN which is supported by Microsoft and other network vendors. This is also the easiest to setup.

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

Next up, `edit /etc/pptpd.conf` with `sudo vi /etc/pptp.conf`. At the bottom add the following lines:

```
localip 192.168.1.10
remoteip 192.168.1.230-239
```

Here localip references the IP of the home server. The `remoteip` variable configures which IPs remote clients may use when the connect through VPN to the network. In this case I reserve 10 IP address: 192.168.1.230 through 192.168.1.239.

With that out of the way, let's tell PPTP which users to allow. Edit `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`, just like you did before using `sudo`.

```
# client    server  secret          IP Address
rose     pptpd   somepassword    *
```

That's all! Just restart the `pptpd` daemon and your VPN server is ready.